# Content scrolling javascript bug, content carries on scrolling up when point of page is reached

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

This is the javascript & css:

```
    $(document).ready(function() {

    /* Every time the window is scrolled ... */
    $(window).scroll( function(){

        /* Check the location of each desired element */
        $('.content-scroll').each( function(i){

            var bottom_of_object = $(this).position().top + $(this).outerHeight();
            var bottom_of_window = $(window).scrollTop() + $(window).height();

            /* Adjust the "200" to either have a delay or that the content starts fading a bit before you reach it  */
            bottom_of_window = bottom_of_window + 800; 

            /* If the object is completely visible in the window, fade it it */
            if( bottom_of_window > bottom_of_object ){

                $(this).animate({'margin-top':'0'},10000);

            }

        }); 

    });

});
```

CSS:

```
.content-scroll { margin-top: 1000px; }
```

I am working on a simple one page wordpress shop website, and have an issue with a script I am using when scrolling to a certain point on a page.

About - Services - Contact - Shop

Each link loads the relevant section of the page correctly, with a smooth effect, but when loading the content in I have implemented some javascript so the content itself within each section scrolls up, as you can see my example test website here:

http://test.flixonstudios.co.uk/

When clicking the Shop link it loads the last section on the page... but as you can see, it kind of judders, and if you scroll up slightly, the scrolling script is still happening.

Can anyone recommend how to make it if I were to for example, click on the Shop link, all of the content above it would load instantly, rather than scroll?

The concept is for a user to go through each section, 1 at a time but once someone has viewed all the content, and returns to the website they would just want to go directly to the shop section.

Any feedback appreciated. Thank you for reading.

Answer (score 0):

You can remove all the scrolling event handlers and just have the sections/nav buttons (About, Services.. etc) have anchor tags that have a hash in the href attribute that corresponds to the section on the page that you want it to navigate to, like in your contact section for example, just add an id of 'contact' inside the h2 element that corresponds with this section, then assign the  tag that you wrap around your nav button ('Contact') an href of `/#contact`

Comment: Thanks for your response... that is pretty much how is it currently setup... when clicking About, Services etc they already jump to the correct section with the relevant ID... the issue is, the content it self within the section, is currently set to scroll up using the above javascript, and when you reach a lower section, it carries on scrolling the above content up, so forces the page up... You will see here, http://test.flixonstudios.co.uk/ - when you click Shop, you can see the page content above is still scrolling up, causing a bug so it judders.